# What is the difference between “to support someone in all they can” and “to support someone with all they can”?

Tags: prepositions

Good day. I am writing to a dear friend of mine, and I don’t want to sound incoherent and inarticulate in my English. He is way older than me. I am like a daughter to him. And English is my native tongue. Since he has been so nice to me and to my family, I want to express my fondness for him because I look up to him as a father figure. Plus, he needs to hear this.

I tried searching up the difference in context between the words “**in**” and “**with**”, yet I am beyond confused. I want to use one of these two words in this sentence:

> They want to support you ____ all they can.

Yes, this can apply to any gender. I want it to be personal. For example, does it make a difference if the pronoun “*she*” is added to the sentence?

> She wants to support you ____ all she can.

Because I prefer this sentence as opposed to the first sentence. And after all, she is female. I need answers.

Comment: You got usage examples for each? A link?

Comment: No, the only writing usage examples I have are in text.

Comment: I think it's more common to hear "in any way they can" or "with all that they can muster"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"support *someone* in" is usually followed by something that the person being supported is doing, e.g.

> I'm going to support you in your bid for school board president.

"support *someone* with" is usually followed by something that the supporter will provide, e.g.

> I'm going to support you with a $500 donation.

If you want to describe more general support, that's usually referred to as a "way".

> I'm going to support you in any way that I can.

Answer (score 0):

To support someone "in all they can" generally wants to potray that one supports the person through thick and thin and in amy situation the person faces, or any task the person the person undertakes.

To support someone "with all they can" would rather be well said as "with all I can" which means to support the person with all the resources possible but not nessecarily in any task they undertake.

Hope the difference is clear to you now.

Comment: Yes, the difference is clear to me now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**support you *in all they can***

-- support you in every one of your endeavors where something doesn't prevent them; perhaps there are some endeavors of yours where they would prefer to demur. Maybe  one of your goals is  to counter climate change by taxing fossils fuels but they're holding public office in a state or province whose economy is in large part based on production of such fuels.

**support you *with all they can***

-- support you with every resource they are able to devote to that purpose.